# I was wondering how do I read a char and output a loop from the char in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am currently using emu8086 for class and I am very new to assembly language. I have created an asm program to display the alphabet for the first 14 letters. I was wondering how do I read a char from an input in the command prompt executed by the compile and run. I was thinking a loop within a loop.
Here's my code so far:

```
include emu8086.inc

org 100h

 MOV CX, 14                 

 MOV AH, 2                      
 MOV DL, 65


 LOOPA-N:                       
   INT 21H                    

   INC DL
   ;INC CH
  ; CMP CH, 14  

  Loop LoopA-N

  ; JNZ LOOPA-N

 MOV AH, 03H
 INT 10H

 MOV AL, 0AH
  MOV AH, 0EH
  INT 10H

  MOV AL, 0DH
  MOV AH, 0EH
  INT 10H

 PRINTN 'Would you like to continue? '
 PRINTN 'Press c to continue ' 
 PRINTN 'Press r to start over, clear the screen, and print in the reverse order, from Z to A '
 PRINTN 'Press x to exit ' 


 c:
 MOV CX, 12
 MOV AH, 2
 MOV DL, 79
 LOOPO-Z:

 INT 21H
 INC DL

 Loop LOOPO-Z


 call GET_STRING


 mov Dl, 0DH
 INT 21H

 MOV DL, 0AH
 INT 21H

 MOV DH, 02H
 INT 10H

 MOV AH, 4CH                  
 INT 21H

 ret
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop within a loop to wait for a certain key to be pressed. Here's an example of how to do it (in NASM syntax):

```
org 0x100

wait_for_input:
  mov dx,msg        ; Display the prompt
  mov ah,9
  int 21h

  mov ah,1          ; READ CHARACTER FROM STANDARD INPUT, WITH ECHO
  int 21h
  cmp al,'c'        ; The character is returned in AL
  je continue
  cmp al,'r'
  je restart
  cmp al,'x'
  je exit
  jmp wait_for_input   ; Try again

continue:
; Do whatever needs to be done here

restart:
; Do whatever needs to be done here

exit:
mov ax,04c00h
int 21h

msg db 13,10,"Press c, r or x: $"
```

[Here's a reference](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm) for all the `INT 21H` functions in case you need it. And [here's the reference](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-10.htm) for `INT 10H`.

---

By the way, you're making a lot of assumptions about the register contents for the interrupt functions you're calling towards the end of your program. I recommend that you set up *all* the registers used by those functions properly - to make the code more readable if nothing else.